# CrudRepository save method not saving to oracle databse

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create an application to save data into the Oracle database using CrudRepository. Here is my repositiry:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findByEmail(String email);

    List<Customer> findByDate(Date date);

    // custom query example and return a stream
    @Query("select c from Customer c where c.email = :email")
    Stream<Customer> findByEmailReturnStream(@Param("email") String email);

}
```

My application.property looks like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@vgdevst-scan.hhs.local:1521/EONDEV.hhslocal
spring.datasource.username=EON_USER
spring.datasource.password=EON_USERD
spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

While my customer entity class is :

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

//http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/id-generation-083058.html
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CUST_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "customer_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1, name = "CUST_SEQ")
Long id;

String name;
String email;

//@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
Date date;

public Customer(String name, String email, Date date) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.date = date;
}

public Customer(Long id, String name, String email, Date date) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.date = date;
}

public Customer() {
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customer{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", date=" + date +
            '}';
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

I am trying to save a new cutomer to database using:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("DATASOURCE = " + dataSource);
        customerRepository.save(new Customer(new Long(4),"Amit","a.r@state.ma.us",new Date()));
        System.out.println("\n1.findAll()...");
        for (Customer customer : customerRepository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not see the new customer added either in sops or in database. What am i missing here?

Comment: do you get an error? did you debug your code?

Comment: No transaction, no saving to database.

Comment: You're trying to save while in read-only transaction, it might be a problem I think.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that you are executing the `save` statement in a *readOnly* transaction. The solution could be as simple as removing that property.

Reading the `readOnly` flag [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#readOnly--), it states that:

> A boolean flag that can be set to true if the transaction is effectively read-only, allowing for corresponding optimizations at runtime.

Use only `@Transactional`:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    // the rest of your code ...
}
```

Comment: I referred following link : https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-oracle  did step-step implementation and was able to write to database. Did not use any @transactional. Do i really need to use it? However, in my original code, when trying the same thing, still not writting to DB.

Comment: Strictly for your case, you actually don't need the `@Transcational` at all. You can remove it. But do you get any errors? Maybe we can debug why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The code was working just fine.
Its just that in my application code, i had changed the application.property file as per my old code and instead of "spring.datasource.url" i had put "appname.datasource.url", which is why code never interacted with DB.